# DIY Fence Screen made with EMT Conduit

Tags: fence, conduit, post, screens

I would like to install some black mesh screening material to hide an area of my yard. I was thinking that I could zip tie the mesh to 3/4” EMT conduit. Any suggestions on easiest way to anchor the tubing in the ground? Ideally I’d like to be able to remove the posts for access. I’m looking for a way to possibly put a slightly larger pipe in the ground to telescope into? Any suggestions on an inexpensive way to do this?

Comment: WARNING: This will act as a sail. As far as posts in the ground, you could pour concrete footings with fittings on top to hold removable poles.

Comment: Looking for anchors or tubing that snugly telescopes. They make pool fencing that does this, but it’s cost prohibitive.

Comment: Check the fit of #4 reinforcing rod (steel bar for reinforcing concrete.) IIRC it might be a reasonable slip fit *inside* 1/2" conduit.

Answer (score 2):

For several decades I have attended a very windy art festival in a desert and learned a few things about anchoring, shade cloth and structures made out of EMT.

The easiest way to anchor it to the ground is to hammer two foot long 1/2" rebar 1' into the ground and use a stainless steel hose clamp to anchor the conduit. Keep in mind that rebar hammered into hard ground might form a sharp edge on top. You can easily pull the rebar by pouring a little water and use a wrench to twist the rebar and pull it out of the ground.

Keep in mind that one of the great qualities of EMT is it is designed to bend. 3/4" will bend easily, 1" EMT is much sturdier, but will still bend. Black shade cloth will act as a wind sail and will bend either in a heavy gust. A fabric like Aluminet will not catch the wind like shade cloth or tarps.

Good luck.

Comment: How do you remove the rebar when you are finished? Do you have to cut it off?

Comment: Pour a little water on the rebar and use a wrench to turn the rebar to loosen, then it pulls out. I do this with three foot spikes into hard dry lake mud and we can pull them out. Or we use a rebar puller.